# Posting to http Spring-boot API from https angular website using aws-amplify

Tags: angular, spring-boot, aws-amplify, aws-certificate-manager

I have angular https website that uses API.post from aws-amplify to post a request to a http Spring-boot api, first it worked locally but when I deployed the code to the cloud I got a mixed content at page error, so I decided to change my api to use https and generated a certificate using keytool, after doing so I started getting

```
ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

So I decided to get a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager but its not as easy as I expected and I don't want to use another service to generate a certificate for me because it a bit expensive and not sure if I'm going to keep using it, so any suggestions for a walk-around to this issue or a step by step tutorial to use AWS Certificate Manager.

I started using it and generated one but could not figure out if what im doing is the right thing, because in my spring application configurations I have the following:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=/path/to/keystore.properties
server.ssl.key-store-type=PEMCFG
server.ssl.key-store-password=dummy
server.ssl.key-alias=keycert
```

and KeyStore.properties:

```
alias=keycert
source.cert=/etc/…/fullchain.pem
source.key=/etc/…/privkey.pem
```

but I did not have any option to set a key-store-password so I got stuck there, Im just looking for an easy and fast to do walk around any suggestions please?

Using AWS-cloudfront I managed to make all my requests get redirected to http and https, but the default is http, so when I type my domain.com it will use http, which is something I don't want, but it can lead to a result if I make the default https and on the page that Im making the post request should use http? does that possible to do?

Comment: I don't know if your requirement is correct, a user can access your website on both http and https, you can't set it bydefault, you can set a redirection for the user or block http at all, in CloudFront, you can set the viewer protocol policy to HTTPS only which would give 403 to the users who tries to access it on HTTP but the ideal would be a redirection, btw, lets encrypt is trusted and free if you want to use.